# Custom UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I am trying to create a custom UIBarbuttonItem that uses just a png with transparency so that I only have an icon as button. When I try to set the button image, set the background as white, and set the style to Plain I still get an inner shadow and black border around it.

What gives?

[image]

I have tried the below code and it still puts the black border around it.

```
UIImage *background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Dismiss_normal.png"];
UIImage *backgroundSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Dismiss_selected.png"];
self.closeButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[self.closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(closeButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; //adding action
[self.closeButton setBackgroundImage:background forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.closeButton setBackgroundImage:backgroundSelected forState:UIControlStateSelected];
self.closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(0 ,0,background.size.width, background.size.height);
self.closeButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.closeButton];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.closeButtonItem;
```

What I noticed is if I do a modal segue the button, with the code above still has a black border around it, but if I do a push segue it doesn't?  WTF?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I understood your problem.

When you actually push a `UIViewController` it will be a part of existing `UINavigationController`. So the `UINavigationBar` retains. But when you use `ModalViewController` its just another `UIViewController` kind of "added" to your existing `UIViewController`. So the `UINavigationBar` won't be there.

But you can add another `UINavigationBar` from `xib` and add a `UIButton`. But don't directly add the `UIButton`, if you do so it will automatically convert to `UIBarButton` making it bordered.

So first drag a normal `UIButton` to your `UIView`(not navigation bar). Change it to custom and add `UIImage` to it using `Attribute Inspector`. Then drag that image to your custom created `UINavigationBar`. It will work as I tried it just now. You can see the screen shot attached below.

[image]

Comment: Actually you even can't access the navigation bar from the view controller which was presented using modal way. So you have to add your own UINavigationBar(Custom).

Comment: I was followed for your steps... This type of button action does not working
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *sidebarButton;
give Outlet action, But button action does not working

Answer (score 15):

You must set the button type to **Custom** and the icon image to the button **background**.
example code:

```
UIImage *background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];
UIImage *backgroundSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_selected.png"];
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButtonTapped:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; //adding action
[button setBackgroundImage:background forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setBackgroundImage:backgroundSelected forState:UIControlStateSelected];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0 ,0,35,35);
```

Then set this button to your BarButtonItem like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton;
```

Comment: you want to make sure that the user has no problem touching the button, with that you should allocate a new UIView with the boundaries that you want to be able to touch, then add the button to this view then initiate the barButton with that newly allocated view instead

Answer (score 4):

**This will update ALL back buttons and navigation bars throughout the app.**

I have used the Following code to set Custom Navigation back button

```
UIImage *imgBack = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_back.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(-6, 22, -6, 0)];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:imgBack forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

and the Following code for Setting background image on navigation bar.

```
UIImage *navBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_bar.png"];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBackgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: It's worth explaining that this will update ALL back buttons and navigation bars throughout the app - likely the best answer.

Comment: sub class the UINavigationController and modify the navigation bar in there and use the sub class as your main navigation tool,

Answer (score 3):

Try use [UIBarButtonItem initWithCustomView]

```
UIImage *menuButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"list.png"];// set your image Name here 
UIButton *btnToggle = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btnToggle setImage:menuButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btnToggle.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, menuButtonImage.size.width, menuButtonImage.size.height);
UIBarButtonItem *menuBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnToggle];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuBarButton;
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally like [FlatUIKit's](https://github.com/Grouper/FlatUIKit) approach by just flattening out the entire UI through UIAppearance

Essentially, you'd do something like:

```
UIImage *backButtonPortraitImage = [UIImage backButtonImageWithColor:color barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault cornerRadius:cornerRadius];
UIImage *highlightedBackButtonPortraitImage = [UIImage backButtonImageWithColor:highlightedColor barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault cornerRadius:cornerRadius];

[appearance setBackButtonBackgroundImage:backButtonPortraitImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[appearance setBackButtonBackgroundImage:highlightedBackButtonPortraitImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

UIImage *buttonImageNormal       = [UIImage imageWithColor:color cornerRadius:cornerRadius];
UIImage *buttonImageHightlighted = [UIImage imageWithColor:highlightedColor cornerRadius:cornerRadius];

[appearance setBackgroundImage:buttonImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[appearance setBackgroundImage:buttonImageHightlighted forState:UIControlStateHighlighted barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg"];
[button setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, btnImage.size.width, btnImage.size.height);
[button addTarget:target action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIImage *icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon"]
UIImageView *iconView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:icon];
iconView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, icon.size.width, icon.size.height);
[button addSubview:iconView];
iconView..userInteractionEnabled=NO;
[iconView centerBothDirections];
[iconView release];
UIBarButtonItem *barbtn = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button] autorelease];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem =barbtn
```